# Angular 2 - Form Data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, form-data

I'm the only one who gets the empty formData {} after making an append
I'm working with angular 2 the latest version.

```
let formData: FormData = new FormData()
   formData.append('key','value')
   console.log(formData)
```

Result:

```
FormData { }
```

Answer (score 3):

`FormData` is not plain js object, API link: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('key', 'value');
console.log(data.get('key'))
```